# Get last updated data - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter, i have a below table of schemes, my problem is i want to show last updated data of each scheme. I dont know how to do that, please help.

**my_table**

```
scheme_code        updated_on            scheme_name
1                  2015-04-13            One
3                  2015-04-12            Three
4                  2015-04-13            Four
3                  2015-04-10            Three
3                  2015-04-8             Three
1                  2015-04-10            One
4                  2015-04-11            Four
```

**My Model**

```
    function show_last_updated_data(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('my_table');
        $this->db->order_by('updated_on', 'DESC');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Output Needed**

```
scheme_code        updated_on            scheme_name
    1              2015-04-13            One
    3              2015-04-12            Three
    4              2015-04-13            Four
```

Comment: Please mention clearly the output format that you want.

Comment: what is the `primary key` of `my_table ?`

Comment: @SureshK Please mark correct to answer you satisfy.

Comment: @ArkarAung i am not satisfied with any suggestions..

Comment: @SureshK Have you check Syed Qarib answer and mime?? I think it got what you want.

Comment: @ArkarAung i checked both answers but didnt get what i want.. Now i am working on below query as it is works in MySql. `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (updated_on) IN (SELECT MAX(updated_on) FROM my_table GROUP BY scheme_code)`

Comment: @SureshK Do you want to convert this to active record format ??

Comment: @ArkarAung yes.. can you try it for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on @Syed Qarib. I modified it to be compatible with codeigniter active record format.

```
function show_last_updated_data() {
    $this->db->select('*, str_to_date(updated_on, "%Y-%M-%d") As date', false); // false to skip escape
    $this->db->from('scheme');
    $this->db->group_by('scheme_code');
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Edit**

In another way,

```
function show_last_updated_data() {
    $max = $this->db->select_max("updated_on")->group_by("scheme_code")->get('scheme')->result_array();
    $updated_on = array();

    if (count($max)) {
        $updated_on = array_column($max, "updated_on"); // make sure your php version is >= 5.5
    }

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("scheme");
    $this->db->where_in("updated_on", $updated_on);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use group by it will retrieve your record based on scheme_code without repeating it and your desire results. :)

```
function show_last_updated_data() {

            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                          ->from('my_table')
                          ->group_by('scheme_code')
                          ->order_by('updated_on', 'DESC')
                          ->get();
            return $query->result();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function show_last_updated_data(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('my_table');
    $this->db->group_by('scheme_name');
    $this->db->order_by('updated_on', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but its not showing recent data its showing the first row

Answer (score 1):

As you have used custom date format, so the ordering will not work correctly until you convert the string to date format. Try this:

```
function show_last_updated_data(){
      $this->db->select('*, str_to_date(updated_on, "%Y-%M-%d") date');
      $this->db->from('my_table');
      $this->db->order_by('date', 'DESC');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
}
```

*Note: It is recommended to use native date/datetime field, do not use custom formats. You can also go for UNIX timestamp and save it in an int field. As the date can be fetched in any format afterwards and will save you hassle like this one.*